# Angularjs and jquery can be combined together in a project?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Say for example, for validation and other purpose i have utilised jquery and for page templating i implemented angularjs. ( i felt it is easier to include angularjs tags directly into your html page like php.)

Since i'm very new to angularjs, i'm not sure about this method. can anyone suggest whether this is a good practice combining together ?

Comment: Angular itself uses it's own light version of jQuery (jqLite), so it is absolutely ok to use them together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are free to combine twice but its not recommended. If you use angular, you should marry that. The use of jQuery would be nice if you use some directives where you can manipulate your dom. That’s where the jQuery goes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can if needed for some other libraries like bootstrap...